# Is there a polite, formal way to say "sh!t happens"?

Tags: politeness, slang

I am trying to write an essay and the only phrase I can think of is "shit happens". I'm wondering; is there any formal way to say *shit happens*?

Comment: *The best laid plans of mice and men often go astray.*

Comment: Excreta happens.

Comment: Dudu occurs. (this is from an old bumper sticker);-)

Comment: What kind of essay is this where you would need to use such a dismissive statement?

Comment: @BlueRaja - That's a fair question. Opinions are not unanimous on this, but there is a longstanding SE policy that discourages the use of vulgar words in the titles of questions. See Jeff Atwood's accepted answer [here](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/975) for one example; the matter is discussed further in the comments under the accepted answer [here](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/6572). This topic is also discussed on [this SE meta question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16565/dont-include-vulgar-words-in-the-url).

Comment: My favourite version of this, or at least of something not too far removed, is Harold Macmillan's "Events, dear boy, events" - which interestingly is linked to 'stuff happens' [here](http://www.theguardian.com/environment/blog/2014/mar/26/events-climate-change-extreme-weather)

Comment: @BlueRaja I agree, and we all know what the word is, but I think it'd become an expectation, for the same reasons newspapers do it.

Comment: I would offer Kurt Vonnegut's idiom from Slaughterhouse Five: "So it goes".

Comment: "Stuff happens" is a very common expression.

Comment: I like "that's the way the cookie crumbles" as an informal but polite idiom.

Answer (score 47):

I think the closest expression with the same meaning and very similar connotations would be the French expression:

> C'est la vie.

meaning

> That's life.

You can use the French phrase as is because it is famous enough to be understood in any English speaking country.

Certainly there are some more possibilities to say it in a polite way as to avoid vulgarity:

> Stuff happens.

or you can use the [English idiom](http://www.usingenglish.com/reference/idioms/worse+things+happen+at+sea.html):

> Worse things happen at sea.

as a way of telling someone not to worry so much about their problems.

Comment: I am not sure if in English *c'est la vie* is equivalent to *shit happens*, but it is not in French. It does not carry the abrupt and strongly negative tone, it is rather light-hearted (usually - not always).

Comment: @WoJ: to me (native English speaker), “shit happens” is not terribly abrupt or negative; it’s usually used to downplay the significance of something that otherwise might be seen as moderately-to-strongly negative.

Comment: @WoJ: I've always understood "shit happens" to be rather light-hearted. Negative tone would be "f**k"

Comment: @MichaelDurrant "stuff happens" is _polite_, however, it's not "formal" and you wouldn't write it in an "essay".

Comment: @WoJ In American English, "shit happens" is rather light-hearted, almost like "eh, go figure". I'm not sure if American English has abrupt and negative equivalents

Answer (score 21):

A polite and reassuring way:

"It could have been worse"

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @MARamezani As a native speaker, I view this an acceptable answer to the original poster's question. Depending upon where you are at in the English speaking world, some people might use this phrase. For example, a quiet, rural Midwestern might use this phrase whereas an urbanite might just use the OP's phrase.

Comment: Original question is not asking for a direct translation, but a way to express the same thing. "Could be worse" or similar does the trick.

Answer (score 17):

Lucian's suggestion of "C'est la vie" is a good one. There are a few other ways you could express the same idea:

Depending on the context, you might want to reference **Murphy's Law.** Murphy's Law is often stated as:

> Anything that can go wrong, will.

This is a phrase you would use if you were talking about things going wrong before they did, or how they could have been avoided.

If you're talking about something going wrong after the fact, and especially something that could not have been prevented, you could also say:

> That's life!

This is a more idiomatic way of phrasing Pazzo's suggestion. The implication is the same: in life, things happen, good and bad, and you just have to deal with it.

For a more literary tone, you could use the Burns quote suggested by TRomano's comment, the actual original phrasing of which is:

> The best-laid schemes o' mice an' men
>
> Gang aft agley

This is often misquoted in more standard English as:

> The best-laid plans of mice and men
>
> Oft go awry.

Comment: It's not "misquoted" any more than the NIV Bible is a "misquoted" version of the KJV Bible. Modern times call for modern words.

Comment: Like your other suggestions, but not keen on referencing Murphy. His law is an engineering precept, meaning that one can and should design such that nothing _can_ go wrong _before_ the event. "Shit happens" is an often post-hoc "explanation" for something going wrong. As such it there denotes a quite contrary mindset.

Answer (score 9):

Things happen in life that we may not like.

or

Bad things happen.

Comment: That's not the same as "shit happens", but much more serious. You dropped your ice cream on the floor: Shit happens. You lost your job: Bad things happen. In each case using the other term would be inappropriate.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the expletive, you could just say "stuff happens", which is somewhat idiomatic (though not nearly so idiomatic as "shit happens").

That's still rather informal but, in the right context and used only occasionally, informality can work well in an essay. It lightens the mood. Be careful not to over-use informality and be careful that it's only a little break from the serious stuff and that it doesn't ruin the flow.

Answer (score -4):

Petanque is a metaphor for life - anything can happen and it usually does

Comment: I don't think this is a good suggestion. Petanque is not at all popular in English-speaking countries so it doesn't make for a strong metaphor.

Comment: While I don't think this is a great answer, I don't think it is low enough quality to delete. It would be improved if you linked to a definition of petanque and explained a little more about how common/formal it is.