# "Life happens"-what it implies?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

***Life Happens, But Only the Strong Survive.***

"Life happens" is it an idiom or a fixed phrase having a special meaning. How I can understand this semantically?

Comment: Only the strong **survive**.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey "life happens" means??

Comment: **Life happens**  is an expression which talks about the acceptance of misfortune/bad luck in one's life.

Comment: @BillyKerr is the saying **informal** & please clear my doubt I stated in the question.

Comment: A more informal and expressive phrase is "shit happens".

Comment: @WeatherVane - or you can say 'stuff happens' to your elderly aunt.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I am the elderly uncle and you can say what you like to me – been there, done that, got the T-shirt.

Comment: [A dictionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/life_happens). Some comments mention "shit happens" which has [already been discussed on this site](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/55517/is-there-a-polite-formal-way-to-say-sht-happens).

Comment: @Sam It's an idiom which could be used formally or informally. However, if you want to put it less idiomatic language, you could say "Misfortune is likely to happen to most people during their lifetime".  I would however say that "Only the strong survive" is perhaps a little Machiavellian, or perhaps lacking in empathy. People can and do help each other overcome adversity.

Comment: @BillyKerr thanks, why this idiom is not listed on any dictionaries?

Comment: Sam... **shit happens** idiomatic phrase vulgar — _used to say that bad things happen as part of life and cannot be prevented_ (Merriam-Webster Dictionary). Also **life happens** phrase. _An expression of acceptance of misfortune and unforeseen bad circumstances or luck._ (Wiktionary, the free dictionary)

Comment: @MichaelHarvey ok, thanks but all dictionaries has not included the definition because It's uncommon expression. (I think)

Comment: It [is listed](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/life_happens#:~:text=Phrase%20%5B%20edit%5D%20life%20happens%20An%20expression%20of,of%20misfortune%20and%20unforeseen%20bad%20circumstances%20or%20luck.) in some dictionaries

Comment: Sam: it's not 'uncommon', just informal, and for that reason some dictionaries will not include it.

Comment: As John Lennon said/sang: [***Life is what happens** to you. While you're busy making other plans.*](https://genius.com/John-lennon-beautiful-boy-darling-boy-lyrics)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Life happens" is an idiom used to express that there are things we can't control, foresee, or prepare for. The future is unknown, and anything could happen.

It is often used to explain how time passes, and people end up in completely different situations than they anticipated, or were in before.

Comment: Why its meaning is not given on any dictionaries?

Comment: @Sam: because its meaning can be understood from the individual words. In place of "Life" one could say "stuff" or "things".  If you were upset because your plane was delayed when you were traveing to a friend's wedding, your friend might say to you on the phone, "Look, things happen"  and the meaning would be "Life does not always unfold as planned."